# Strange response in browser using NancyFX, self hosting and mono

Tags: mono, nancy, self-hosting

Here is my test code:

```
public class MyModule : NancyModule
{
  public MyModule()
  {
    Get["/resources/{resourceId}"] = x =>
    {
      var kurt = (string)x.resourceId;
      return Response.AsText(kurt);
    };
  }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    using (var host = new NancyHost(new Uri("http://localhost:1234")))
    {
      host.Start();
      Console.WriteLine("Running on http://localhost:1234");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this from VS it works as expected, but when I host the .exe using mono.exe I get this in the browser:

```
P/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Server: Mono-HTTPAPI/1.0
Date: Fri, 07 Oct 2016 10:58:32 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Keep-Alive: timeout=15,max=100

4
test
0
```

Seems that the response header is understood by the browser. But why?

Comment: Mono version: Mono JIT compiler version 4.6.1 (Visual Studio built mono)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           normal
        SIGSEGV:       normal
        Notification:  Thread + polling
        Architecture:  x86
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen

Comment: Works with Mono version 3.12.1, but real application uses types that are not in 3.12.1...